# LISP - Set a property from a list to an object from a list (bought having same index)

Tags: lisp

I am looking for a function which should do something like this:

```
(function 'set-number '(1 2 3) '(number1 number2 number3))
```

Can I do it using some function from LISP?(maybe `apply`)

Or the only solution is to use `dolist`/ `dotimes` ?

Edit: The efect should be : `set-number number 1` , `set-number number2 2`, `set- number number3 3` where `number1`, `number2`, `number3` are some slots and `set-number` is a method.

Comment: what should the function do? what should the effect be?

Comment: @RainerJoswig I'm editing the post now

Comment: slots of what??

Comment: @RainerJoswig slots of a class. My syntax isn't important. Take it like a pseudocode.

Comment: if it's not important, why mention 'methods' and 'slots'?

Comment: If `'(number1 number2 number3)` are slot names and `'(1 2 3)` are values why do you need `'set-number`? Is this going to return a function that does this to an object you supply later? If not you are missing the actual argument with the object.

Comment: what's wrong with with DOLIST and DOTIMES? Why not just use that if you have a solution?

Comment: @Sylwester It's just an example: In my code I need to set for each semaphore a semaphore-phase. Something like: `set-semaphore-phase (semaphore1 semaphore2 semaphore3) (phase1 phase2 phase3`
@RainerJoswig I am just interested if I can do it in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Common Lisp you can use [mapc](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcar):

```
(mapc #'set-number
      '(number1 number2 number3)
      '(1 2 3))
```